# Cannot reinstall Python 3.5

Tags: python, installation, reinstall, python-3.5

I have troubles installing Python on Windows. Here is what I did so far:

1) installed Python

2) added PATH

3) tried "python" and "python3" command in cmd. It didnt recognize it.

4) uninstalled python and removed PATH. Downloaded installation file again and ran it.

Setup fails because of some (look like?) leftover files. Please check added screenshot.

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN8aw.png)

Comment: What did the logfile say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may mean that you have some leftover files, along with registry still referring to python 3.5. You may need to run a program like Revo Unistaller, that in advance mode will look for all the leftover parts of previous installation. Revo Unistaller is free . Did you remove the python 3.5 folder?